# How to fix "pub get failed(1)"

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i wanted to build a Flutter App which is using firestore. I implement Firestore and when i am click on "Packages get" this error came.

```
The current Dart SDK version is 2.1.0-dev.9.4.flutter-f9ebf21297.
Because kegel_app requires SDK version >=1.19.0 <2.0.0-dev.infinity, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1)
```

How can i fix this? :/

Pubspec.yaml

```
version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
    sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

 cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
 cloud_firestore: ^0.2.6

 dev_dependencies:
   flutter_test:
     sdk: flutter

 flutter:
   uses-material-design: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**kegel_app is a dependency**

> Because kegel_app requires SDK version >=1.19.0 <2.0.0-dev.infinity"

this tells that this package depends on a very old Flutter version that used Dart 1 or Dart 2 pre-releases.
`<2.0.0-` (with `-` after the build number) means only Dart versions that are `<2.0.0` or `== 2.0.0` but pre-releases.

This package is not compatible with recent Flutter versions and needs to be updated.

**kegel_app is your project**

Change the SDK version constraint in `pubspec.yaml` to

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"
```

Comment: Andorid studio say, all is up to date

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear. The package needs to be modified to make it compatible with recent Flutter versions. Either contact the author or clone it and re-publish under a new name.

Comment: Sry but i dont know how to do this.

Comment: Now i switched flutter channel to dev and Upgraded all. flutter version 1.1.5     Dart 2.1.1

Comment: Is `kegel_app` your project? Sorry, I assumed this is  pub package you are using. I updated my answer.

Comment: Yes `kegel_app` is my project.

Comment: but i updated flutter and dart. now the same error is shown....     ``The current Dart SDK version is 2.1.1-dev.0.1.flutter-d1817ddc91.`
`
Because kegel_app depends on cloud_firestore >=0.0.4 <0.3.0 which requires SDK version >=1.8.0 <2.0.0-dev.infinity, version solving failed.
`
pub get failed (1)`    i changed the `environment`

Comment: Xou need to update version constraints of cloud_firestore in pubspec.yaml to allow the newest version (check pub.dartlang.com for available versions)

Comment: Thanks. now it works. I am new to this, so i am not so good with it.

Comment: Glad to hear. No prob :)